# MySQL: More Efficient Way to query millions of rows and find the unique values

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

I am trying to find a more efficient way to query millions of rows and find the unique values of one of the columns.

Let's say the Dataframe below is queired out from an SQL table with tens of millions of rows, it is only a fraction of the SQL table as an illustration.

```
x = ["ABCDEFG", "2021-09-24 00:00:34", "ABCDE_ABCD_label.0", "60186339", "ABCD770", "4157"]
y = ["ABCDEFG", "2021-09-24 00:00:34", "ABCDE_ABCD_label.0", "60186346", "ABCD770", "4157"]
z = ["ABCDEFG", "2021-09-24 00:00:34", "ABCDE_ABCD_label.0", "60186386", "ABCD770", "4157"]
a = ["ABCDEFG", "2021-09-24 00:00:34", "ABCDE_ABCD_label.0", "60186426", "ABCD770", "4157"]
b = ["ABCDEFG", "2021-09-24 00:00:34", "ABCDE_ABCD_label.0", "60186387", "WXYZ991", "4157"]
c = ["ABCDEFG", "2021-09-24 00:00:34", "ABCDE_ABCD_label.0", "60186389", "WXYZ991", "4157"]

test_df = pd.DataFrame([x,y,z,a,b,c],columns=["PRI_KEY_A","PRI_KEY_B","PRI_KEY_C","PRI_KEY_D","Column_E","Column_F"])

print(test_df)
```

It looks like this.

```
  PRI_KEY_A            PRI_KEY_B           PRI_KEY_C PRI_KEY_D Column_E Column_F
0   ABCDEFG  2021-09-24 00:00:34  ABCDE_ABCD_label.0  60186339  ABCD770     4157
1   ABCDEFG  2021-09-24 00:00:34  ABCDE_ABCD_label.0  60186346  ABCD770     4157
2   ABCDEFG  2021-09-24 00:00:34  ABCDE_ABCD_label.0  60186386  ABCD770     4157
3   ABCDEFG  2021-09-24 00:00:34  ABCDE_ABCD_label.0  60186426  ABCD770     4157
4   ABCDEFG  2021-09-24 00:00:34  ABCDE_ABCD_label.0  60186387  WXYZ991     4157
5   ABCDEFG  2021-09-24 00:00:34  ABCDE_ABCD_label.0  60186389  WXYZ991     4157
```

Imagine the above dataframe is an SQL table, the first 4 columns are the primary key (but I don't know why there are duplicates since primary key column should be unique.), and the last two are just normal columns.

The query command I used for the above table is:

`SELECT PRI_KEY_A, PRI_KEY_B, PRI_KEY_C, PRI_KEY_D, Column_E, Column_F from TABLE where PRI_KEY_B between '2021-09-24 00:00:34'and '2021-09-24 00:00:35' LIMIT 6")`

As you see from `PRI_KEY_B` column, within 0.01 second, there are already 6 rows of data (actually there are hundreds of rows within 0.01 second in the SQL table), and `Column_E` has two unique values `ABCD770` and `WXYZ991`.

I had tried to query 100000 rows, it took around 2 mins. But the queried data only covers `2021-09-24 00:00:34` and `2021-09-24 00:01:25` in column `PRI_KEY_B`.

I would like to know if there is a more efficient/faster way to query all the data between two timings, let's say `2021-09-01 00:00:00` and `2021-09-30 23:59:59` (which will be millions of rows), and then to group all the data by `Column_E` to find the unique values.

Thank you!

Comment: What are your indexes and execute plain?

Comment: Sorry, I am very new to SQL, what do you mean by indexes and execute plain?

Comment: Did you create any indexes? Did you really need to use  `100000` rows in one query? otherwise I would suggest you use limit and create correctly indexes

Comment: I did not create any indexes. Yes, I do need all the data which satisfy my condition where PRI_KEY_B between 2021-09-01 00:00:00 and 2021-09-30 23:59:59, which i think will be more than millions rows of data, then I want to find the unique values in Column_E.

Comment: I cannot create indexes in the SQL table, I do not have write access

Answer (score 0):

SELECT DISTINCT a, b, c, d FROM ... [WHERE ...]

Will find all the different combinations of a,b,c,d that exist in the table, optionally filtered by the Where clause.

It is unlikely that there is a faster way.

If you have `PRIMARY KEY(a,b,c,d)` then the *combination* is unique, *not* any given set.  That is, these combinations could be valid PKs:

```
a,b,c,d
- - - -
1,1,1,1
1,1,1,2
3,2,1,1
1,2,3,4
7,7,7,7
```

A fast way to check whether (a,b,c,d) has no dups:

```
ALTER TABLE t ADD UNIQUE(a,b,c,d)
```

It will fail if there are any dups.  (But it won't tell you anything else.  And it will leave behind an extra `INDEX` if it succeeds.)